# How to filter column according to it's name in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have `boolean` value in the database and in my `GridView` I'm trying to filter it according to the `name`, not `id`.

I did that in the other column and it worked, but somehow, this column does not. Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

```
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_name', $this->customer_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'item.name', $this->item_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sign', $this->sign])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_surname', $this->customer_surname])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_phone', $this->customer_phone])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_email', $this->customer_email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'code', $this->code])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'comment', $this->comment]);
```

I did that for `item.name`, which is from different database table and it worked. I need to do the same to the `sign` column, that it would be filtering according to `Approved` or `Denied`, not by `id's`. How to do that?

Comment: And by saying `this column does not`, what exactly is not working? Zero rows or totally ignoring filtering?

Comment: Are you comparing a boolean to a string? If the two only alternatives are Approved or Denied, a dropdown with options 1 => Approved and 0 => Denied should do the trick. Also: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a boolen values  you should not use a like operator but and equal  operator

```
 ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'sign', $this->sign])
```

Comment: Equal (=) operator finds only 0 (false) values

Comment: are you sure that $this->sign is a boolean and iw not converted  is some way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, because in an `ActiveForm` i made it as a checkbox value. Also checked in the database, its `tinyint(1)`. Interesting situation here

Comment: try check the real content of the $this->sign  .. eg: var_dump($this->sign) and let me know

Comment: Sry I'm new to `Yii2`. Just tried to add `var_dump($this->sign)` and `exit;` after the ` ->andFilterWhere` conditions and it printed me `string(0) ""`. Is this what you want?

Comment: seems that your $this->sign is not a boolean but an empty string .. so this could explain why you obtain  return only for false.  could be that is an implicit cast for empty string to int hat is 0

Comment: I don't get how it can be an empty string if the values printed are `1 = Approved` and `0 = Dissaproved`. Do you have an idea how could I solve this solution?